# Taking Average and Median by Month and then Ordering by Date and Factor in R

Tags: r

Lets suppose I have the following data:

```
set.seed(123)
Dates <- c("2013-10-07","2013-10-14","2013-11-21","2013-11-28" , "2013-12-04" , "2013-12-11","2013-01-18","2013-01-18")
Dates.New <- c(Dates,Dates)
Values  <- sample(seq(1:10),16,replace = TRUE)
Factor <- c(rep("Group 1",8),rep("Group 2",8))
df <- data.frame(Dates.New,Values,Factor)
df[sample(1:nrow(df)),]
```

This returns

```
   Dates.New Values  Factor
4  2013-11-28      9 Group 1
1  2013-10-07      3 Group 1
5  2013-12-04     10 Group 1
13 2013-12-04      7 Group 2
11 2013-11-21     10 Group 2
8  2013-01-18      9 Group 1
7  2013-01-18      6 Group 1
9  2013-10-07      6 Group 2
6  2013-12-11      1 Group 1
14 2013-12-11      6 Group 2
16 2013-01-18      9 Group 2
3  2013-11-21      5 Group 1
2  2013-10-14      8 Group 1
15 2013-01-18      2 Group 2
12 2013-11-28      5 Group 2
10 2013-10-14      5 Group 2
```

What I am trying to do here is find the monthly average and median for both of my factors then order each group by month in a new data frame. So the new data frame would have a median and average for months 10,11,12,1 for `Group 1` bundled together and the next 4 rows would have the median and average for months 10,11,12,1 for `Group 2`bundled together as well. I am open to packages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution. The question seems to be looking for both mean and median.  See if this suits your need.

```
library(zoo); library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Mean = mean(Values),
                 Median = median(Values)),
          by = list(Factor, as.yearmon(Dates.New))][order(Factor, as.yearmon)]
#     Factor as.yearmon Mean Median
# 1: Group 1   Jan 2013  7.5    7.5
# 2: Group 1   Oct 2013  5.5    5.5
# 3: Group 1   Nov 2013  7.0    7.0
# 4: Group 1   Dec 2013  5.5    5.5
# 5: Group 2   Jan 2013  5.5    5.5
# 6: Group 2   Oct 2013  5.5    5.5
# 7: Group 2   Nov 2013  7.5    7.5
# 8: Group 2   Dec 2013  6.5    6.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
df$Dates.New <- as.Date(df$Dates.New)
library(zoo)   # for as.yearmon(...)
result <- aggregate(Values~as.yearmon(Dates.New)+Factor,df,mean)
names(result)[1] <- "Year.Mon"
result
#   Year.Mon  Factor Values
# 1 Jan 2013 Group 1    7.5
# 2 Oct 2013 Group 1    5.5
# 3 Nov 2013 Group 1    7.0
# 4 Dec 2013 Group 1    5.5
# 5 Jan 2013 Group 2    5.5
# 6 Oct 2013 Group 2    5.5
# 7 Nov 2013 Group 2    7.5
# 8 Dec 2013 Group 2    6.5
```